# What is default --execution <strategy> and recommended value for node/validator operator?

Tags: substrate-node, wasm, validator, executor

When executing node as a validator, the documentation states here that there is differents execution strategy available, however as this is optionnal switches, what is default if nothing is set ?
https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/node-template/#build-spec

And what execution mode would be recommended as a validator ?

Thanks !
Regards

Answer (score 2):

It is advised to use the `wasm` executor. The `native` executor will be removed in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for this info ! And do you know if it's the default strategy if no --execution switch is passed ?